# update_attributes for many objects with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

Is possible something like:

```
@users = User.criteria.for_ids(params[:user_ids])
@users.update_all(:suspend => true)
```

instead of:

```
for u in @users
 u.suspend = true
 u.update_attributes
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
# Updating one record:
Person.update(15, :user_name => 'Samuel', :group => 'expert')

# Updating multiple records:
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

Seen here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

> *Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.*

**In your case:**

```
User.update(params[:user_ids], :suspend => true)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Arf, didn't take attention to that, sorry ... :/

Answer (score 3):

As long as `for_ids` method returns a criteria(instead of an array), you can use `update_all`.

```
@users = User.criteria.for_ids(params[:user_ids])
@users.update_all(:suspend => true)
```

The `update_all` call gets translated in to a `set` call. Refer to the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#query_plus) for more details.